# How to garbage collect an Idris/C Struct?

Tags: c, struct, ffi, idris

I'd like Idris to garbage-collect my Idris `Struct`. [The docs for `Struct` FFI](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#structs) say

> The field types of a Struct can be any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - `Ptr a` or `AnyPtr` (`void*` in C)
> - Another `Struct`, which is a pointer to a `struct` in C

and [offer the following functions](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#finalisers) from the `Prelude` to enable garbage collection on pointers

```
onCollect : Ptr t -> (Ptr t -> IO ()) -> IO (GCPtr t)
onCollectAny : AnyPtr -> (AnyPtr -> IO ()) -> IO GCAnyPtr
```

Having read the quote above, I'd think it's possible to use these functions for automatic memory management of my Idris `Struct` (that perhaps `Struct` is a wrapper/alias for `Ptr`), but looking at the definitions of `Struct` and `Ptr`

```
data Struct : String -> List (String, Type) -> Type where

data Ptr : Type -> Type where [external]
```

that appears not to be the case. Is there some way to automatically memory manage structs in Idris?

Comment: Does it work if `believe_me` the struct into a pointer?

Comment: @michaelmesser I don't know. It's probably too complicated to just try it out esp given how difficult it would be to test

Comment: If your Idris `Struct` contains / wraps pointers that ultimately were or could have been provided by C functions then correct GC depends handling those appropriately.  This is very difficult to automate correctly, at least in the general case.  You might want to read up on the [Boehm garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) for C and C++.